# Compare two tables and add missing records into the main table from subtable

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables .. table A and table B ... I need to compare the two tables ..and if any new record is present in table b which is not present in table a .. I need to add that to table A . What is the best method to do this ?

I tried comparing the two tables using a left join with table b being the left table ..

Wherever id col was null in table a
The corresponding row was added from table a to b

Comment: Hi, you should include details of the query attempts that you have made - it does sound like potentially the SELECT portion of your query may be correct, but the INSERT portion is incorrect (given that you're saying you ended up with records in table "b", instead of table "a")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a query format that u can try for the purpose

```
INSERT INTO TableA (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM TableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.uniqueColumn = TableB.uniqueColumn
);
```

Comment: Thank u for the quick response

Comment: You are welcome Sid. I would like to help logic issues like these as a support to fellow developers. Please do not hesitate to send me an email explaining your new requirement at gemunu.rohana@hotmail.co.uk I should be able to put some time to it among my other tasks. Kindly share my email with any of your friends needing similar support.